# juju maas bootstrap error 401

Tags: juju, maas

I am new to juju and each time I try to bootstrap juju it gives me following error message:

```
$ juju quickstart
juju quickstart v1.4.2
bootstrapping the maas environment (type: maas)
juju-quickstart: error: WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/test/.juju/environments/maas.jenv"
ERROR gomaasapi: got error back from server: 401 OK (Authorization Error: Invalid API key.)
```

Can anyone please help? I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find  solution.

Comment: It looks like your API key is incorrect. Check your `environments.yaml` and make sure the `maas-oauth` field matches your API key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the cached copy `/home/test/.juju/environments/maas.jenv`, then make sure `/home/test/.juju/environments.yaml` has the right MAAS API key, and try again.